# Объединение скриптов

Tags: php, html, mysql

Вот php код №1:

```
$result88 = mysql_query("SELECT login,avatar,name,number FROM users ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 4",$db); 
            $myrow88 = mysql_fetch_array($result88);
      do {
   echo("<img src='$myrow88[avatar]'>");
             echo ($myrow88['login']);
              echo ($myrow88['name']);
               echo ($myrow88['number']);

} 
while ($myrow88 = mysql_fetch_array($result88));
```

Вот php код №2, в который нужно вставить php код №1:

```
<?php
            if    (!isset($myrow['login']) or $myrow['login']=='') 
            {

            .
print <<<HERE

<table >

<tr>

<td background="Stopka.jpg" valign="top" width="225px">
</td>

<td>
 <h3 style=" padding-left:35px; padding-top:20px;">Главная страница</h3>
 <hr style=" position:absolute; left:260px; top:40px" width=700px>
//ВОТ СЮДА НАДО ВСТАВИТЬ СКРИПТ №1. КАК ЭТО СДЕЛАТЬ?

</tr>
</table>
<img src="inyourcity.png" style="position:absolute; top:160px; left:467px" />

HERE;
//далее еще пара условий
?>
```

Comment: `$result88` лол) Мы счастье в каждый дом приносим)) 

*не все поймут*

Comment: Sh4dow - видимо он так именовал чтобы они не конфликтовали с прежними вызовами) я помню тоже переживал про такое дело и вообще в функцию заносил всё это дело чтобы сделать локальными))  
я это делал зря? ни о каких конфликтах не может идти и речи?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Зачем много говнокода? не проще написать в строчку и не городить кучу ненужного хлама, сам потом не разберешься!

file1.php будет так выглядеть

```
$result= mysql_query("SELECT login,avatar,name,number FROM users ORDER BY RAND()LIMIT ",$db); 
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
   echo "<img src=\"$row['avatar']\">".$row['login']." ".$row['name']." ".$row['number']."<br />";
```

file2.php так

```
<?
            if    (!isset($myrow['login']) or $myrow['login']=='') 
            {
                $content .='<table><tr>
                 <td background="Stopka.jpg" valign="top" width="225px"></td>
                 <td>
                 <h3 style="padding-left:35px; padding-top:20px;">Главная страница</h3>
                 <hr style="position:absolute; left:260px; top:40px; width=700px">';
          $content.=include("file1.php"); // вроде при выводе должно прокатить такое. :)
         $content .='</td></tr>    // тут советую еще тег <td> закрыть!
        </table>
        <img src="inyourcity.png" style="position:absolute; top:160px; left:467px" />';
        }

?>
```

Вот и все. В чем трабл?

Но оговорюсь сразу, что условие

```
if    (!isset($myrow['login']) or $myrow['login']=='')
```

скорее всего не сработает, т.к. откуда берутся эти значения???

Comment: @Shrek это конечно выводит, но таблицы нету. Пытаюсь вставить по другому, весь стиль сбивается!

Comment: Так вопрос нужно ставить правильно!Естественно тут все собъется. Совсем немного подумать нужно и правильно оформить код.

Comment: @Shrek, Я хз как) прост у меня уже была таблица между тегами `print<<<HERE HERE;`, но если записать в столбец `$content.=include("file1.php");` он это в виде текста воспримет. Помоги)))

Comment: @Shrek помог только 1 код, но в нем еще ошибка есть)

Answer (score 1):

Используйте [выражение include](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.include.php).
Пример:

```
include('file_name.php');
```

Comment: @LordySL определитесь, что Вам нужно

Comment: это не работает. Скрипт выводит данные из мускл, а мне нужно чтоб он выводил их в столбце таблицы.!

Comment: @LaKO, я ничего не понял.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте описать вопрос более конкретно. Комментатор выше прав по поводу include или же вы можете "перемешивать" html код с php кодом, для этого в любом месте html пишите:

```
<?php
//код php  
?>
```

Например:

```
 <table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Имя</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php
    $query = "SELECT * FROM users";
    $res = mysql_query($query);
    while($arr=mysql_fetch_assoc($res))
    {>?
       <tr>
          <td><?=$arr['ID']?></td>
          <td><?=$arr['NAME']?></td>
       </tr>
    <?}?>
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php

    $result88 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM 'users' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 4",$db);

    $myrow88 = mysql_fetch_array($result88);

    do {
        while ($myrow88 = mysql_fetch_array($result88));

        if    (!isset($myrow['login']) or $myrow['login']=='')
            {
                printf  ("<table >
                        <tr>
                            <td background='Stopka.jpg' valign='top' width='225px'>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <h3 style=' padding-left:35px; padding-top:20px;'>Главная фыфыстраца/h3>
                            <hr style=' position:absolute; left:260px; top:40px' width=700px>
                            <img src='%s'> %s %s %s %s
                            </tr>
                     </table>
                        <img src='inyourcity.png' style='position:absolute; top:160px; left:467px' />",

                                    $myrow88['avatar']
                                    $myrow88['login'],
                                    $myrow88['name'],
                                    $myrow88['number']);
            }

       } 
    while ($myrow88 = mysql_fetch_array ($result88));
?>
```

Comment: это что за код ужасный такой??
не много ли
>while ($myrow88 = mysql_fetch_array ($result88));

в цикле нет? Да и вообще попробуй его глазами пробежать и понять что этот код сделает. Сколько лишних движений и неправдоподобных выводов он даст!